# Apache configuration - Can authentication by group and also by individual users?

Tags: apache, authentication, httpd.conf

I would like to know if I can merge group and specific users authorisation.

I have in my httpd.conf something like:

```
   <Directory /path/to/dir>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Private pages"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /path/to/dir/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /path/to/dir/.htgroup
    Require user user1 user2 user3
    Require group group1 group2
   </Directory>
```

Then I access it from browser. I use user1, I did not success and I got, in the error_log, the error:

```
 Authorization of user user1 to access /path/to/dir failed, reason: user is not part of the 'require'ed group(s).
```

Can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the user would have to match both the user directive AND the group directive. You should be able to use the

```
Satisfy Any
```

setting if you want just the group or the user directive to match

Comment: When I add the 'Satisfy Any' it allow to access the page without any authentication.

Comment: Hmm. You got any more directives in there? There are more things that could allow access, like "Allow from".

Comment: No, I have nothing but the lines I mention.